# Regex for Mediawiki replacement

Tags: regex, mediawiki

I am using the [Replace Text extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Replace_Text) in MW 1.23 (which uses [MySQL regexps](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)) and I want to run regexes that will result in replacements like the ones in the examples below. The point is that it should find only matches that have a single Greek (extended/polytonic) word between the tags or just a word failing that.

Replacing this bit first:

```
<b class="b3">
```

and then the second one:

```
</b>
```

Is not an option as there are other instances that should not be replaced.

Examples:
First string of each example is the actual string, second string the way it should be after the replacement. The Greek word could be any Greek word (here "σπυρίς" and "ὑσμίνη"):

```
1.
Dim. of <b class="b3">σπυρίς</b>
Dim. of [[σπυρίς]]

2.
cf. <b class="b3">ὑσμίνη</b>
cf. [[ὑσμίνη]]
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: I could not find any way to match a single word between the tags, thank you for your comment -:)

Comment: Add what you try anyway, it will help us to teach you best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for the following pattern:

```
<b class="b3">([^\s-\.]*?[σπυρίς]+?[^\s-\.]*?)<\/b>
```

And replace it with that:

```
[[$1]]
```

*`[σπυρίς]` can be extended with any greek character you want to have at least in between the tags.*

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, the problem is that it would match the space character, multi word instances, and other characters like -, which I do not want matched. For example:

`cf. <b class="b3">ἀφ-, ἐπαφ-αυαίνω</b>` or
`cf. <b class="b3">Βορόην· τὴν φῦσαν</b>` or
`cf. <b class="b3">ἀκτή, καρπός</b>`

I strictly want it to match single words.

Comment: @greektranslator I've adapted the regular expression (`.*?`→ `\S*?`) . It won't match anymore, if there is any whitespace character in between the tags. If you want to exclude also other characters, like numbers, you could also use the following exclusion set instead of `\S*?`: `[^\s0-9]*?`

Comment: Thanks, that is better, but it still matches words that contain dash or fullstop, I.e. `<b class="b3">-ρεως</b>` or `cf. <b class="b3">κελλίβας.</b>`

Comment: Like I said, you can use an exclusion set and exclude every character you don't want: `[^\s-\.]*?` for everything except spaces and dashes and dots. I'll adapt it again...